# How to set Other C flags in xCode for multi-targets?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Condition:

I have 3 targets in a xCode iOS project.
Each target have 3 `Other C Flags` sub items which are:

Other C Flags:

- Debug
- Developer
- Release

these 3 items have different settings.

**Question**:

I want to add some new settings to all targets
(with all items like Developer, Debug included). e.g. `-DIPAD -DDEBUG`

How can I do this?

Comment: Tried write OTHER_CFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos*][arch=*] = $(inherited) $(MY_DEF) in xcconfig file, But not work!

Answer (score 0):

Add the settings to the project and the targets will inherit them.

Comment: And if you need 'em across multiple projects, add them to an xcconfig file and include that in each project.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your way, create a new xcconfig file. but I don't know what "key name" I should use. I tried OTHER_CFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos*][arch=*] = $(inherited) $(MY_DEF), but it did not work.

Comment: http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/300-Build_Settings/bs_build_settings.html